# is there any way to see content of an array in a java program while program is running in debug mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is there any way to see content of an array in a java program while program is running in debug mode? 
I mean just like scripting languages. 
I put a break point after the line of code that changed an array content, now haw can i see the content of the array?
I use eclipse as IDE.
thanks

Comment: Use the variable window in eclipse during debug mode

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in the debug mode and once you reach the code line with the array right click on the array name and choose inspect. it will show you the value.if the value shown in inspect is not the expected value then simply step to the next code line and inspect the array name again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely. Use "Debug" icon in the toolbar and run your program and switch to debug perspective and use the variable window to check the array value.

[image]

Comment: My impression is that OP already knows about debug mode. The question is not how to start the debug mode, the question is how to see the array. If you exchange the screenshot by something more relevant, the answer would be much better.